# Does the center of a perfect group not contain all elements of prime order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite perfect group (i.e. $G=G'$) and $Z(G)$ be its center.

I don't know whether this statement is correct:

> There exists an element $x$ of *prime order* such that $x\notin Z(G)$.

A quick check on CFSG gives that this holds for every (quasi-)simple group. But what if $G$ is a general finite perfect group? Or is there any further descriptions on the center of perfect groups?

---

Another description on this question is (also I don't know if this holds):

> Let $H$ be a center-less (insoluble) group (i.e. $Z(H)=1$). Then there always exists a prime divisor $p$ of $|H|$ such that the $p$-part of the Schur multiplicator of $H$ is trivial.

Is there any result on both?

Comment: For the first question I don't even know a counterexample to the the stronger question, given a finite perfect group $G$ and odd  prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, does there $x \in G \setminus Z(G)$ of order $p$?

Comment: I originally thought it meant that and said that $\mathrm{SL}_2(q)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have now updated my answer to answer both the OP's and your question.

Comment: Originally I thought that if the second statement holds then the first follows. Now even if the second fails (Derek Holt's example in his answer), the first one also holds (David Carven's answer for a more general case).

Comment: I think the first would follow from the second, but of course the converse is not true. Thus the second can fail while the first succeeds.

Comment: That's why I asked the second: the first was my original question and the second was my attempt (though failed).@DavidCraven

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short version: if $p$ is odd and all elements of order $p$ are central in $G$, then $G$ has a normal $p$-complement, i.e., a normal $p'$-subgroup $K$ such that $|G:K|$ is a power of $p$. This follows from Theorem 5.3.10 from Gorenstein, which states that if $p$ is odd and a $p'$-automorphism of a $p$-group $P$ acts trivially on $\Omega_1(P)$ then it is the identity.

Thus, if $G$ has this property for any odd prime then $G$ is not perfect, because it has a $p$-quotient.

Original post follows, which says things about $p=2$, and I leave here for posterity, and for noting that I completely forgot about that theorem from Gorenstein's book.

---

I originally thought you meant every prime dividing $|G|$. This question is a lot harder than I first thought.

Notice that the property that all elements of prime order being central is inherited by subgroups. In particular, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then the soluble residual of $H$, i.e., the last term in the derived series for $H$, satisfies your conditions.

Let's start with $p=2$, and let $G$ be a counterexample to your claim. Bob Griess proved in the 1978 paper *Finite groups whose involutions lie in the center* that if all involutions of $G$ lie in the centre of $G$ and $O_{2'}(G)=1$ then the soluble residual of $G$ is a direct product of $\mathrm{SL}_2(q)$s, or a central extension of $A_7$.

Let $H$ be the normal subgroup $O_{2'}(G)X$, where $X$ is one of the direct factors, and let $H_1=H^{(\infty)}$ be its soluble residual. Then $H_1$ is also a
counterexample, and is non-trivial as it has a simple composition factor. Thus $H_1=G$, and we may assume that $X=G/O_{2'}(G)=\mathrm{SL}_2(q)$ or $A_7$.

Now I have to leave, but my current plan is to choose a prime $p$ such that the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $X$ is cyclic, quotient out by $O_{p'}(G)$, and show that the Sylow $p$-subgroup doesn't have the property. I will return! Unless someone else solves it first.

EDIT!!! I should have read Bob's paper more. Remark: if $p$ is an odd prime and $G$ has this property for elements of order $p$ then $G$ is $p$-nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you for both the edited answer and the original one: that gives a stronger statement for the first question (both on $p$ odd and $p=2$).

Answer (score 6):

Your second question is much easier. Yes there exist centreless - and even perfect - finite groups $G$ such that the $p$-part of the Schur Multiplier of $G$ is nontrivial for all primes $p$ dividing $|G|$.

For example there is such a group with structure $(3^4 \times 5^3):A_5$. The primes dividing the order are $2,3,5$ and the Schur Multiplier has order $30$. You can construct lots of examples in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $G$ is not trivial. Since $G'=G$, then $G$ is not abelian and $Z(G)$ is a proper subset of $G$. Pick an element $g$ of $G-Z(G)$ and consider the subgroup $H=\langle g\rangle$. If every element of $H$ with prime order is in $Z(G)$, then $H\leq Z(G)$, which is false since $g\notin Z(G)$. Therefore, at least one of those elements is not in $Z(G)$.

EDIT:
From the comments below I realized that "If every element of $H$ with prime order is in $Z(G)$, then $H\leq Z(G)$" is false. The proof works only if the order of $g$ is a product of distinct primes... which is not the general case.

Comment: What? I think I missed how $H\cap Z(G)\neq 1$ becomes $H\leq Z(G)$. For example, quaternion $2$-groups have this property. You need to use perfection, not merely non-abelian.

Comment: If $g$ has order $p^n$ then how does $g^{p^{n-1}}\in Z(G)$ give $g\in Z(G)$?

Comment: $H$ is cyclic and finite. Does this answer both questions?

Comment: @ Myself No, it doesn't. I am wrong. Sorry